# What is the declarable for the image in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload an image to the MySQL database using a SQL query.

```
query = "INSERT INTO requests (image ,type, user_id ,account_id  ,value ,date) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?, ?, ?)";
              $insert = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
              $insert->bind_param('ssiiiis', $image,$type, $userId,$account_id,$value,$date);
              $insert->execute();
              $insert->store_result();
              $creationWasSuccessful = $insert->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
```

So I'm just wondering which parameter type should I mention for the `$image` and `$date` ? 
Currently I used `ssiiiis` which is not working properly.

If you need additional info, just let me know.

Comment: it is generally recommended not to store images(any file\binary) in the db. store their name\path, and the file in the *file*system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `b` for `blob` which should be the MySQL field type for the image as well.

```
$insert->bind_param('bsiiis', $image, $type, $userId, $account_id, $value, $date);
```

Comment: @user1012181: For `bind_param()` `date` is a string.  I made an assumption about `value`, if its not an int use string or double whichever it is.

Comment: learn the basics. Dont store the imagedata in the database. You can use the database for referencing. date/time can be stored as UNIX_TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP or DATE.

Answer (score 1):

A point worth noting is that you are not obliged to bind the params. You can just execute the query with an array containing your values

```
   $values = array($image,$type, $userId,$account_id,$value,$date);
   $insert->execute($values);
```